# Linux Shell printf - How to print %?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I am trying to print ***%*** with the `printf` command.
Unfortunately the backslash as escape character is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%%` to print a literal `%` character:

```
$ printf '%%\n'
%
```

`man printf` describes the behaviour of the `printf` executable. Some shells (e.g. bash) provide their own implementation - in this case, some extra information can be found in `man bash`.

Comment: thank you a lot. I coudn't find it on the Internet. Maybe I searched somehow wrong...